# IntelliJ setting path variable?

Tags: java, python, macos, intellij-idea, path

I'm trying to set a path variable because I'm executing command on my Mac using Runtime.getRuntime().exec();. They work when pressing the "play" button in IntelliJ, and also when running from command line, however, not when double-clicking.

I have found that I should set the PATH variable. In terminal, the PATH variable is

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/binsr/bin:/bin

Which is also weird, because of the /binsr but that doesn't matter that much. I want to make IntelliJ set the PATH variable of my application to this. The documentation and some other answers say it is in here:

> File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Path Variables

But there is no "Settings" under "File"!!

There is a "Preferences" on Mac, and it does have a Build, Execution and Deployment, but that doesn't have path variables??!!?

This is really frustrating me, and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Sten

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question: Go to the menu item on the top called "IntelliJ Idea" and under that you'll find a "Preferences item"